# Does SQL Server job wait to finish the currently executing call before starting the next schedule call?

Tags: sql-server, job-scheduling

I have created a sql server job which runs a stored procedure. I have scheduled this job to run at every 10 seconds.

Now my question is, If a job is running and it takes more than 10seconds (lets say it takes 20sec), is there a chance that sql job will start the next schedule?

Comment: One option would be to put your processing logic in a thread safe "service agent" model if it is mission critical. Via MSSQL you lose control over thread assignments.

Comment: @AnandPhadke - I believe the linked question adequate to answer yours. If I'm wrong, I have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: @ LievenKeersmaekers -- Its exactly waht I am looking for.Thanks

Comment: @AnandPhadke - I was going to comment that I would expect the jobscheduler to just start a new job nonetheless. I would have been very wrong :).